# Question on application of Borel-Cantelli lemma

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I have an exercise in my measure theory class which goes as following:

If $(X,A,\mu)$, where $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, is a measure space and $(B_n),n=1,2,\ldots$ a sequence of sets in $A$. Show that if $\mu(B_n)\to 0$ and   $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_{n+1} - B_n) < +\infty$, then $\mu(\limsup B_n)=0$.

(Where $\limsup B_n:=\bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} B_n$.)

I’ve had some thoughts but I can’t gather them to end in a solution.

For example, I know from the Borel-Cantelli lemma that  $\mu(\limsup (B_{n+1} - B_n)=0$, but I just can’t connect the dots for this one. Every help would be gladly appreciated. I’m very interested in the solution of course, but I’m more interested in understanding the thought behind it…

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: $\lim \sup B_n \subseteq \lim \sup (B_{n+1}\setminus B_n) \cup (\lim \inf B_n)$.

Comment: I have edited the question. If you don't like it I can restore your version.

Comment: @geetha290krm thanks for the edit, I don’t know how to use the correct notation but I’m currently reading the information the other commenter send

Comment: @geetha290krm about the hint: does this mean that we only need to prove that the measure of liminfBn is also zero?

Comment: Yes, that is what the hint says.

Comment: @geetha290krm So this is what I ended up with: μ(limsupBn)<= μ(limsup B_n+1 - Bn) + μ(liminfBn). Also μ(liminfBn)=μ(U(k=1 to inf.) ⋂ (n=k to inf) Bn) <= Σ (n=1 to inf) μ(⋂ (n=k to inf) Bn) <= and this is where I get stuck. If i say that it’s <= Σ(n=1 to inf) μ(Bn) does this converge to 0?

Comment: @geetha290krm Do we know that Σμ(Bn) < ∞, because Σμ(B_n+1 - Bn)< ∞, and if so, why?

Comment: $\mu (\bigcap_{n\geq k} B_n)\leq \mu (B_k) \to 0$.

Comment: From your Measuer Theory class you should know that $\mu(\lim \inf B_n)\leq \lim \inf \mu(B_n)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm ok so Σ μ(⋂n≥kBn)<= Σμ(Bk) ( where k=1 to infinity). But why does this converge?

Comment: @geetha290krm I didn’t know that, we’ve just started the chapter with measures, maybe that’s why. I’m just trying to solve exercises from the end of the chapter(but my textbook doesn’t say a lot about limsup and liminf of sets either)